# Microsoft oledb provider for oracle is not working for Oracle 19c

Tags: oledb, oracle19c

I am working on a desktop application. Our desktop application supports Oracle DB as well.

To connect to Oracle DB we are using Microsoft oledb provider for oracle. It is working well till i connect to Oracle 12c.

Now when we use Oracle 18C or later version then my application crashes while opening the connection.

Please see the code snippet below :

```
Dim dtb As ADODB.Connection
Dim conn As String
conn = "Provider=MSDAORA;" & "Data Source=INRT" & ";Password=abc@908" & 
";User ID=system"
dtb.open(conn, "system", "abc@908", 
ADODB.ConnectOptionEnum.adAsyncConnect)
```

Here it is throwing an error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." and crashes.

Note : Using Oracle 19c client(32bit) i am able to setup the connection using above details.

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Exception information:
Exception type: AccessViolationException
Exception message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

MSDAORA is deprecated, Change Provider=MSDAORA to below

Standard Security

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Oracle
Trusted Connection
This one specifies OS authentication to be used when connecting to an Oracle database.

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=MyOracleDB;OSAuthent=1;
```